# Comparing data using custom dimensions in GA4, based on cookie values

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to run a 50/50 AB test on the new theme for my website, versus the old theme.

To serve the themes 50/50, I have script, dropping a cookie with the theme version. The user is then served the theme corresponding to the cookie and value.

So the user has one of the following cookies:

cookie name / cookie value

- theme_old: 1
- theme_new: 1

In GA4, how can I compare the performance of the themes. e.g:

- new theme has a purchase conversion rate of 1.6%
- old theme has a purchase conversion rate of 1.8%

Here's what I've done so far:

1. created 2 User-Defined Variables in GTM, of '1st Party Cookie' type:

- GA4 - Theme Cookie - New
- GA4 - Theme Cookie - Old

2. created 2 triggers in GTM, of 'page view' event type.

Trigger name / Trigger type /  Filter

- theme-cookie-old / Page view / where theme_old cookie value = "1"
- theme-cookie-new / Page view / where theme_new cookie value = "1"

3. Created a new GA4 Event tag, with event name 'get_theme_versions':

user properties / value

- theme_old / {{GA4 - Theme Cookie - Old}}
- theme_new / {{GA4 - Theme Cookie - New}}

With both triggers added from step 2.

4. Added 2 custom dimensions in GA4:

Dimension Name / Scope / User Property

- Theme Old / User / theme_old
- Theme New / User / theme_new

When I preview these changes in GA4 debug, the get_theme_versions event is fired with each page view.

[GA4 debug mode output showing multiple instances of get_theme_versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsxBM.png)

Is this the correct way to approach this, or should I be only firing the event once, at the beginning of the session (and if so, how do I do that)?